# DateTime parsing not working in Windows 7: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-7, datetime-parsing

Before i begin to explain ,i need to tell I have tried all the possible solutions for this problem that are provided in stackoverflow. But doesn't work in windows 7.

On windows 7 parsing datetime is not working.
i have tried the following code snippets

```
DateTime.ParseExact(arr[TransactionDateIndex], "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);
DateTime.ParseExact(arr[TransactionDateIndex], "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(arr[TransactionDateIndex]).ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have an input file which has a transaction date column and it can be in any valid Date-Time Format, right now in the file its (MM/dd/YYYY) which i need to convert to "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" format.
When running in XP this code works fine but in windows 7 even after trying       ParseExact  its showing the error.
Even if i use

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime))  
{
}
```

While running in windows 7,few records will be treated as invalid but same things will be parsed in XP.

Comment: In datetime parse exact you  provide the format you want to parse not the format you want to parse into .

Comment: Without seeing the input data that are failing, there's not much I can say here.

Comment: However "yyyy-MM-dd" also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you r current datetime format is `MM/dd/yyyy`
then you should use as

```
   string dateString = "02/15/2015"
   DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString , "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And if you want to convert that to some other format like you mentioned `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` then you can add the `.Tostring('M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt')` to the date.

As read trough your question one more time you mentioned that **it can be in any valid Date-Time Format** if that is so and if your cultureInfo is fixed.

You can use something like the following, but be aware that more than one format might be able to parse the same date. For example 10/11/12 can be parsed as `yyyy/MM/dd` or `MM/dd/yyyy`, which are both valid US date formats. `MM/dd/yyyy` is more common, so it appears first in the list and is the one returned by the code below (if you use it with a US culture instead of the culture in the example).

```
 string testValue = "02/15/2015";

 DateTime result; 
 CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sl-SI"); 
 string[] fmts = ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", fmts)); 
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(testValue, fmts, ci,    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result)) { 
      Console.WriteLine(result.ToLongDateString());   
 }
```

And if the `CultureInfo` is also not fixed then you should fetch all the available countercultures  and then get all formats from them and then parse the date time .

Comment: I had even tried first parsing the string with valid datetime say _"MM/dd/yyyy"_ with ' Datetime.ParseExact' and then converting it into _"M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"_ but same error occurs when the values like 12/21/2013 or 02-12-2013 or 2/13/2013 (valid formats) etc are parsed.Other wise for the values like 02/12/2013 the code works fine even in windows 7.Im really not able to understand where am i going wrong.

Comment: In `12/21/2013 ` this case it should convert to the date. But  in this `02-12-2013 or 2/13/2013` the your parse exact format and the date formats are not matching thats why error if your culture is fixed then you should try out the below code for all available formats parsing. First do only parsing to check if all dates gets parsed correctly then convert them to your needed format.

Comment: Sry to bother.One more query why is it runs perfectly in xp.even with this Code ' DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(arr[TransactionDateIndex]).ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"),null); ' or this 'DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(arr[TransactionDate]).ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")); ' code. even if the parse exact format and date format arent matching it actually runs in xp i.e 12/21/2013,02/12/2013,2/12/2013 all these values get parsed without parse.exact also.

Comment: It shouldn't have. Try to debug on XP and find out why this works if not then Ask as different question with details.I dont have any details what is going on with your code so I can not give you definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that there is an invalid date in

```
arr[TransactionDateIndex]
```

So try with a hard-coded date first. then you could check all the values passed to date.parse using debug.write() (windows app) or trance.write() (asp.net) by using debug class in System.Diagnostics and check the output window for any inconsistent date format.

Finally you could place this code at the top of the method where this code appears:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: It should have been comment. If you are telling him to do the debugging.